# Does the OWIN OpenID Connect Middleware support the Resource Owner flow

Tags: openid, owin-security

All the examples I've seen using Microsoft's OWIN OpenID Connect Middleware (i.e. the  `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`) use either the Authorization Code, Implicit Flow or Hybrids Flows.

Does this middle ware also support the Resource Owner flow and if so are there an examples?

Answer (score 0):

OpenID Connect specification itself doesn't support the Resource Owner flow. Therefore I don't expect any vendor to implement this. http://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-core-1_0.html

Comment: The answer to the linked question was "Yes, OpenID Connect supports all OAuth 2.0 grant types including Resource Owner Password Credentials Grant and Client Credentials Grant" which contradict your answer

Comment: You are correct, I removed the link. I have overread the content quickly. Basically Client Credentials grant doesn't make any sense for openid connect as there is no user involved. In my understanding, it was a discision made by the openid connect group to not take resource owner grant to openid connect grops. Unfortunately I cant find the mail archive where this group discussed about this.